# Alternate methods of inserting image apart from using the graphicx module?

Tags: graphics, templates

I'm working with the "nature" template that doesn't allow me to use the \includegraphics command. I want to insert an image. Is there any alternate way to go about doing it?

PS: I've tried editing the nature.cls file i.e., trying to comment out the \includegraphics and the subsequent line of command, but as soon as I try to save the file I get a pop-up - "Access Denied".

Comment: They won't have any objection to that macro, but rather an objection to including images inline, don't the author instructions say to send the images separately or some such? It's never a good idea to edit  journal supplied class file!

Comment: It's for a term paper which has been asked to follow the nature format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using this class:

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nature

The comments make clear that images should not be included inline:

```
%% The \includegraphics command is ignored since Nature wants figures
%% as separate files.
```

Thus changing macros would not really help.

If you really want to do it anyway then

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\realincludegraphics\includegraphics
\AtBeginDocument{\let\includegraphics\realincludegraphics}
```

will put the original definition back.